# Can you split India in distinct focal points to travel to?

Tags: india, south-india, north-india

India is quite [appetising](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Sn_jFlcSYw) and visiting the country is on my bucket list. However, where to start that is the question. You more or less subdivide the US, In a northern and southern west coast, a northern and southern east coast, the rocky mountains, the south and the mid-west. You can hop around, but trying to visit multiple of these regions in one trip would mean you miss a lot, at least in my opinion.

Although there are multiple places I would like to visit, like Kerala, Goa, [Majoli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkZDSqyE1do), Kolkata, etc. all scattered over India. I guess to have reasonable amount of time to enjoy it all, I would need to make several trips. Only how would you subdivide India in distinct travel focal points, to allow reasonable time to explore that region?

Comment: How long are you going to spend???

Comment: By andra's wishes, I'd suggest 3 months.

Comment: To clarify, I don't want to do it all in one trip. I usually have 1 months to 6 weeks of travel time available.

Comment: OK so I think my answer takes this into consideration

Answer (score 11):

India is vast and it is not possible to visit every part. And every corner in India has its own culture.Its a very diverse country and so its called "Unity in Diversity!" You might need years to just experience it. But if you have limited time this should help]

1) **Southern India** - Land in Mumbai enjoy couple of days here (Ajanta and Ellora Caves don't forget) and then go to Goa, then go to Karnataka (Mysore and touch base Bangalore), fly to Kerala (gods own country),touchbase Munnar and stay on house boat for a day and experience it, from there go to Kanyakumari, Pondicherry and Chennai and then to Hyderabad[keep atleast couple of days here][try Tirupati if you can. This will be another experience]. This should take you atleast 3-4 weeks with heavy travelling.

2) **Northern- Western India** - All historic places in Delhi,[Jim Corbett National Park. I won't miss this but if you don't wish leave it] Jammu & Kasmir, Chandigarh, Rajasthan(Jaipur, Udaipur, Jaisalmer), Gujarat(don't miss the rann of Kutch) Atleast 3weeks

3) **Eastern India** - Land in Kolkata and experience kolkata. Historic place, Amazing food, Sweets etc. Then travel to Orissa. Puri, lots of temples from olden times, lakes etc. [Eastern part of india is very very beautiful. There are some amazing spots in Assam and Nagaland but check the current safety situation before planning.] [Atleast 2 weeks]

4) **Andaman** is beautiful and make a short 3 to 4days trip to enjoy it.

Whatever I write its very less. I cannot cover everything. It's humanly not possible. Please plan early and do research about each section before you go. In India **Tripadvisor** will have lot of updates and reviews. For food try **zomato** or other online sites to do research. For booking tickets use online websites to do research before going to agents. Some good website like **cleartrip**, **irctc** etc. You get trains for every place. Its cheap but takes time.

[Note:
To experience India you need to eat. Eat everywhere you go. Take medicine on time and eat and eat. Don't miss anything. There is awesomeness in every corner and you will find new things every where.

If you have any Indian friend, brainwash :P him to come with you. Go to his home. Have some home made food. It will add more joy and you will get more details about the culture.
]

[And if you are one of those who likes things to be taken care of then there are reliable websites like Yatra.com, makemytrip, thomascook etc who can create a package. Tell them these options and they should take care. I have very good experience with Yatra.]

All the best and enjoy the nirvana.

Answer (score 6):

For me the time is of importance - the whole tourist industry is based on this.

There are three ways I think of India when 'partitioning' it:

- The first would be by the parts that are affected by the monsoon
  season (there are two main ones in India) and according to the time of your
  visit.
- The next "division" I would make would be:

  Northwest, Northeast, Middle South

  It makes sense as the land is bigger on the North and the travel
  times are greater. Also if you are planning many trips even better!
- The third would be by states or group of states - some are more
  similar to their neighboring ones than other. You choose.

Also, by no means I would hop around as you say as I prefer to see few things and live them than put a 'tick' on them all.

Anyway you decide to see it, leave some time for change in plans. Maybe New Delhi is too much for you and you decide to take a plane to Kerala. Who knows!

Comment: I would include the mountains in a category all by themselves, and the Andaman islands in the Southern category.

Comment: True that. Andaman must be another world altogether. For the mountains I consider them to be North West and North East parts.

Comment: I would consider the tourist belts of Rajasthan, Agra, Punjab as "North west" and consider the mountains separately; since the best season to visit Delhi (in the winters?) is not the same as for visiting Leh for example.

Comment: it´s a point yes. too many ways of seeing it!